# Using JS to expand/collapse divs with FAQs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add some questions/answers to my site. At first I just want it to display the questions, then the answer if the user clicks on the question. This works so far, but how do I get it so the current question closes when another is clicked on? aka there should only be one question open at a time

**HTML**

```
<div class="FAQs">

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>


<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>  

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".question").click(function () {

    $question = $(this);
    $answer = $question.next();
    $answer.slideToggle(500, function () {
        $question.text(function () {
            return $answer.is(":visible") ? $.question : $.question;
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Add `$(this).slideToggle();` at the end.

Comment: I've accomplished this in the past by using JQueryUI's Accordion - https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ as you're already using JQuery, Accordion maybe worth looking at?

Comment: What's the purpose of `return $answer.is(":visible") ? $.question : $.question;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you show the clicked one hide all other `.answer` elements:

> $('.answer').slideUp();

```js
$(".question").click(function() {
  $('.answer').slideUp();
  $question = $(this);
  $answer = $question.next();
  $answer.slideToggle(500, function() {
    $question.text(function() {
      return $answer.is(":visible") ? $.question : $.question;
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FAQs">
  <div class="question"><span>Question?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question"><span>Question?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question"><span>Question?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question"><span>Question?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question"><span>Question?</span>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>Answer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `$answer.slideToggle(500, function()` to `$answer.stop().slideToggle(500, function()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".question").click(function (e) {
    $question = $(this);
    $answer = $question.next();
    $(".answer").slideUp();
    $answer.stop().slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
.answer
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqs">

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>


<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

<div class="question"><span>Question?</span></div>
    <div class="answer">
        <p>Answer</p>
    </div>  

</div>
```